# What happens to mercenary units that die during an outbreak mission?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

I'm not very far into the game yet, but I've played a couple of missions where I accidentally killed my infantry team with my artillery team. Every time this occurs I have restarted because I wasn't sure if the killed units would be permanently gone after the mission.

Does anyone know what happens to units that are killed during a mission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your units won't die permanently if you shell them with artillery (or they are otherwise killed during a mission), and they will still gain XP for zombies they killed before their untimely demise.

However, they will miss out on potential XP they could gain had they survived to kill more zombies during the course of the mission.